# R / Lavaan / rmsea=0, srmr=0, cfi=1, tli=1 what is issue

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I want to ask you guys about some CFA question in R.

When I do cfa for A1, A2, A3 factors using CFA in R, I've got model goodness of fit as like the image below.

```
A <- 'A1 =~ A_1_1 + A_1_2 + A_1_3 
A2 =~ A_2_1 + A_2_2
A3 =~ A_3_1 + A_3_2 + A_3_3
A_1_1 ~~ A_1_1
A_1_2 ~~ A_1_2
A_1_3 ~~ A_1_3
A_2_1 ~~ A_2_1
A_2_2 ~~ A_2_2
A_3_1 ~~ A_3_1
A_3_2 ~~ A_3_2
A_3_3 ~~ A_3_3'

A_fit <- cfa(A, fixed.x=F, data=data)
summary(A_fit, standardized=T, fit.measures=T)

Result
**CMIN = 112.793 / 
DF = 41.00 / 
P-Value = 0.000 / 
RMSEA = 0.053 /
SRMR = 0.021 /
CFI = 0.986 /
TLI = 0.981**
```

But after I got this result, I also wanted to use cfa for each A1, A2, A3 factors.
So I did cfa for only A1 and the result are like the below.

```
A <- 'A1 =~ A_1_1 + A_1_2 + A_1_3 
A_1_1 ~~ A_1_1
A_1_2 ~~ A_1_2
A_1_3 ~~ A_1_3'

A_fit <- cfa(A, fixed.x=F, data=data)
summary(A_fit, standardized=T, fit.measures=T)

Result
**CMIN = 0 / 
DF = 0 / 
P-Value = NA / 
RMSEA = 0 /
SRMR = 0 /
CFI = 1 /
TLI = 1**
```

R system didn't mention about any error, but I think this is not a good sign for my result.

Is it possible to know each A1, A2, A3's goodness of fit?
If I did wrong? What can I do next?

Thank you guys,
and sorry for my bad English writing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your model is just identified (df=0), that's the reason you get such results of p-value = NA, RMSEA=0, etc.

If your model is just

> A1 =~ A_1_1 + A_1_2 + A_1_3

You must be able to run CFA, but because you are letting all indicators correlate each other, you decreased its degrees of freedom and it becomes just identified

The results of each latent variable alone will be useless, so the recommendation is to rely on the model with the 3 latent variables. It shows the model implied covariance matrix fits well the data implied covariance matrix.

Note: this is a more conceptual/stats question, so you will get a more interesting result if you post this kind of question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, not here.